# Maintain a connection without polling in socketserver handle()

Tags: python, sockets, events

I'm looking for a way to maintain a connecion with the python socketserver. I want to avoid the following situations.

**Polling the input**

Example:

```
class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            message = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            ... do something with message
```

What I'm doing is continuously checking if something has been received. I want to avoid this because the server is ran on Raspberry pi so I want as minimum unnecessary computation as possible.

---

**Update: 3/28/2013**

It seems that the socket.recv() is a blocking call. According to the documentation for [socketserver](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html):

> The difference is that the readline() call in the second handler will
>   call recv() multiple times until it encounters a newline character,
>   while the single recv() call in the first handler will just return
>   what has been sent from the client in one sendall() call.

Which means that if socket.recv() is a blocking call, then the `while True` doesn't result in constant checking if a new message has arrived and doesn't consume the processor as I initially thought.

---

**One connection per message**

Example:

```
class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            message = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            ... do something with message
```

This closes the connection once the message is received. However, the messages are sent every 60ms so the client initializes a new connection every time. This brings an overhead to a connection which should be as quick as possible.

**Question**

Is there a way to get some sort of 'interrupt' every time the message is received?

(Conceptual) Example:

```
class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        if interrupt:
            message = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            ... do something with message
```

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14323295/1214214) before, however this question sums up the essence of the problems which were not directly approached in the former question.

Comment: Take a look at: http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and implemented a version for my own benefit.

```
import asyncore, socket, time, signal, sys

finished = None

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.send(data)

    def handle_close(self):
        print 'Closing connection from %s' % repr(self.getpeername())
        self.close()

class Listner(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)
        self.number_accepted = 1

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
            handler = EchoHandler(sock)
            self.number_accepted-=1
        if self.number_accepted < 0:
            finished = 1

client = Listner('127.0.0.1', 1033)
asyncore.loop()

while not finished:
    time.sleep(1)
```